# React child element calling the parent element, on value

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to create a MessageBox(Modal Box) element which gets inputs to form the Modal Box, The close method in MessageBox somehow doesn't call the parent close and inturn get the Modal disappear, any help please ??

export default class MessageBox extends Component{

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
}

close(){
    this.props.callbackParent;
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={this.props.visibility} onHide={this.close}>
                <ModalHeader closeButton>
                    <ModalTitle>{this.props.msgHeader}</ModalTitle>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>{this.props.msgBody}</ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default class Product extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._initState = {
        showModal: false
    }
    this.state = this._initState;
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
}

open(){
    this.setState(
        { showModal: true }
    );
}

close(){
    this.setState(
        { showModal: false }
    );
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}>
                Go!!!
            </Button>
            <MessageBox visibility={this.state.showModal} msgHeader='Header goes here ...' msgBody='Overlay message body goes here ..' callbackParent={this.close}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

};

Comment: You're missing parens in MessageBox's `close` function.. you need `this.props.callbackParent()` to actually call it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the parenthesis on in the close method of MessageBox.

```
this.props.callbackParent;
```

should be

```
this.props.callbackParent();
```

(thx to @azium) for the answer.

Comment: Appreciate your time to reply, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by this

```
export default class MessageBox extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={this.props.visibility} onHide={this.props.callbackParent}>
                <ModalHeader closeButton>
                    <ModalTitle>{this.props.msgHeader}</ModalTitle>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>{this.props.msgBody}</ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.callbackParent}>Close</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}